# Integration - separable equations

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to integrate: `dx/dt = bx(1-x)` so I have the general solution for `x(t)`

I've separated it so I now have: `1/bx(1-x) = dt` and that `dx = du/1-2bx` which leads to `ln(1-2bx) = dx`. However I'm not sure if I should change this into an exponent or should I leave it as it is?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your method of solution looks incorrect before the step you're asking about. Try formatting it correctly and maybe it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer seems wrong. Instead, you should get by separating:
$$\ln\left ( \left | \frac{x}{1-x} \right | \right ) = bt+c; \quad \quad b, c\in \mathbb{R}, x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left \{ 0, 1 \right \}$$

Hint: use $\frac{1}{x(x+1)} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Finally, you can exponentiate in the end as $e^{x}$ is bijective on $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+} \setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}$, meaning:

$$e^{x} = a \Leftrightarrow x = \ln(a)$$ On the positive reals.

Comment: So I have x/1-x = e^c * e^(kt). How would I go about equating this to x(t)? Thanks

Comment: What you have there is an equation of the form x(t)/(1-x(t)) = y(t). Then x(t) = y(t)/(1+y(t)), where y(t) = e^c + e^(kt).